# Converting DateTime to nvarchar, just month and year

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

How to convert the datetime value to nvarchar and want to format it "Month, Year" e-g October 1st 2009 value should get converted to "October, 2009"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use this:

```
select CONVERT(nvarchar(50),   DATENAME(m, getdate()) 
                               + ', ' 
                               + DATENAME(yyyy, getdate())
              )
```

OUTPUT:

```
--------------------------------------------------
October, 2009

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: If he wants to put it into a variable already declared as nvarchar, the convert is not needed as it will implicitly convert at the time the information is placed in the variable. The only place I know of where varchar data doesn't implicitly convert is in SSIS.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
DECLARE @DateTime DATETIME

SET @DateTime = '01 Oct 2009'

SELECT @DateTime

SELECT DATENAME(mm, @DateTime) + ', ' + CAST(DATEPART(yy, @DateTime) AS VARCHAR(4))
```

Comment: does not return nvarchar as OP requests

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use datename to extract the pieces you needed in name format, so:

select Convert(nvarchar,datename(m,getdate())) + N', ' + Convert(nvarchar,datename
(yy,getdate()))

And replace getdate() with your date variable / field.

Comment: would be more efficient to convert everything at one time to nvarchar. also don't forget, if you don't specify a nvarchar length in the CONVERT, it defaults to 30 and will truncate. for example run this _SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar,'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890')_ you only get the first 30 characters and will not see the truncated characters: "567890", and there is no error or warning.

Answer (score 0):

The DateName function will provide the formatting you require:

```
DATENAME(m, date) + ', ' + DATENAME(yyyy, date)
```

Converting  to nvarchar of a specific size can be done through the cast function:

```
CAST(value AS nvarchar[30])
```

Comment: Datepart will return only the numbers, need datename

Comment: Datepart is the numeric representation, not the name representation unfortunately.

Comment: you need DATENAME() for the year too, like my answer, otherwise: Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'October, ' to data type int.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query:

```
Select case  Convert(int, day(getdate())) when 1 then '1st' when 2 then '2nd'
 when 3 then '3rd' else Convert(varchar, day(getdate()))+'th' end +' '+ Convert(varchar, Datename(m,getdate()))+' ' +Convert(varchar, Datename(yy,getdate()))  as Date
```

You can replace **getdate()** with any other date.

Please check if it helps.